# Observable Java class: clearChanged() and notify observers ... what order?

Tags: java

If we look at the JavaDoc for the `Observable` `notifyObservers()` method, we read the following:

"...then notify all of its observers and then call the clearChanged method to indicate that this object has no longer changed."

This is pretty unambiguous (to me).  What happens is that we notify each registered observer and **THEN** the `clearChanged()` method is invoked.  However, in my testing, what I was finding was that the  `clearChanged()` method was being invoked and **THEN** the registered observers were being called.  The order which is documented is reversed from the order of what I seem to actually see.

I then examined the source for Observable and seem to find that experienced behavior (`clearChanged()` and **THEN** notified observables is what is coded to happen).

Given that this class has been around since Java 1.1, I must believe that I am somehow incorrect in my assumption that the observers are called and then `clearChanged()` is called.  Can anyone see where my thinking is incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is correct. Look at the source code for  Observable:

```
  public void notifyObservers() {
    notifyObservers(null);
}
```

and

```
  public void notifyObservers(Object arg) {
    /*
     * a temporary array buffer, used as a snapshot of the state of
     * current Observers.
     */
    Object[] arrLocal;

    synchronized (this) {

        if (!changed)
            return;
        arrLocal = obs.toArray();
        clearChanged();
    }

    for (int i = arrLocal.length-1; i>=0; i--)
        ((Observer)arrLocal[i]).update(this, arg);
}
```

What you describe is exactly what happens - clearChanged() is called before everything is updated.

Probably just a typo in the Java Docs - Good job on finding it ;)

EDIT: Code from [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#notifyObservers()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#notifyObservers%28%29)

Comment: Hi Dean, thanks for the response.  The interesting thing (to me) is that in my solution I actually desire clearChanged() to be called AFTER the notifications made to the observers.  Here is my thinking ...

I have created a sub-class of Observable which contains a history of changes made to that Observable.  I want this history "cleared" when I know that anyone interested in it has seen it.  Hence I have overridden clearChanged() to clear the history but it is being called before the observers get a chance to see the history.

Comment: Hey, yes I think the best way to switch the order they're called to what you want is to extend the class. However, instead of overriding clearChanged, I suggest you override notifyObserver(Object o), and flip the order